# How to give XML as input in soapui testing a webservice

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soapui

I have a webservice. I have to test it using soap UI. but when I have to test it my input xml should be hardcoded inside the webservice implementation class. But I have to give xml input from SOAPUI. How to give like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
 <implmentation><input xml><header>.........</header></input xml> </implementation>
</soap:Envelope>
```

When I give like this it throws "javax.xml.bind.unmarshalexception the parsing instruction target [xX] [mX][lL] are not allowed"

Comment: SoapUI will generate sample SOAP request for you. You can use that instead of hardcoded. Which version of SOAP UI you are using?

Comment: 5.0.0 . But I have to test with the actual input

Comment: Please post more details so that we can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

It throws "javax.xml.bind.unmarshalexception the parsing instruction target [xX] [mX][lL] are not allowed" because tag "input xml" is not allowed due to not allowed "xml" parsing instruction.

So your service responded in the way it should - not allowing to invoke it with invalid xml.

Comment: could you please explain it with additional details